# Spring Boot Criteria API Subquery correlation Invalid Path

Tags: spring, jpa, criteria-api

I am having an invalid path issue with Hibernate and Spring JPA Criteria API. I have the following error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'generatedAlias4.applicationId' [select generatedAlias0 from ie.ul.ethics.scieng.applications.models.applications.Application as generatedAlias0 where :param0 in (select generatedAlias1.username from ie.ul.ethics.scieng.applications.models.applications.SubmittedApplication as generatedAlias2 inner join generatedAlias2.assignedCommitteeMembers as generatedAlias3 inner join generatedAlias3.user as generatedAlias1 where generatedAlias3.applicationId=generatedAlias4.applicationId)

Basically, the alias generatedAlias4 is presumably an alias that was meant to appear from a JOIN performed somewhere but the alias is not defined anywhere in the SQL leading to the error.

The SQL I am trying to emulate is:

> SELECT a
> FROM SubmittedApplication a
> WHERE 'test' IN(SELECT m.username FROM SubmittedApplication a1 JOIN AssignedCommitteeMember assigned JOIN User WHERE a.applicationId = a1.applicationId);

I understand that might not be correct HQL (quickly wrote it to give a rough idea) but I am using the CriteriaQuery and CriteriaBuilder API to dynamically create the query.

The code creating the query is as follows:

```
    CriteriaQuery<Object> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery();
    Root<SubmittedApplication> applicationRoot = query.from(SubmittedApplication.class);

    Subquery<String> subQuery = query.subquery(String.class);
    Root<SubmittedApplication> subApplication = subQuery.from(SubmittedApplication.class);
    Root<SubmittedApplication> correlated = subQuery.correlate(applicationRoot);

    Join<?, ?> assignedJoin = subApplication.joinList("assignedCommitteeMembers");
    Join<?, ?> assignedUserJoin = assignedJoin.join("user");
    subQuery.select(assignedUserJoin.get("username"));
    subQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(assignedJoin.get("applicationId"), correlated.get("applicationId")));

    query.select(applicationRoot)
            .where(criteriaBuilder.in(criteriaBuilder.literal(criteria.getValue())).value(subQuery));

    return query.getRestriction();
```

It returns a Predicate for use in a Specification to search using a repository extending the JpaSpecificationExecutor interface. I used correlate to correlate the application root into the subquery, which theoretically means the last of the subquery where statement should be `where generatedAlias3.applicationId=generatedAlias0.applicationId` and not `generatedAlias3.applicationId=generatedAlias4.applicationId`

The query is meant to ask, find all Applications where the username 'test' exists in the list of AssignedCommitteeMembers. The SubmittedApplication class is a subclass of the Application class (a class that represents an application form being created on the system) that contains a list with OneToMany mapping of these AssignedCommitteeMembers. The first I noticed, selects from the base Application class. Shouldn't it be selected from the SubmittedApplication class? Could this be the issue? `select generatedAlias0 from ie.ul.ethics.scieng.applications.models.applications.Application as generatedAlias0` instead of `select generatedAlias0 from ie.ul.ethics.scieng.applications.models.applications.SubmittedApplication as generatedAlias0`

The entity for the SubmittedApplication class (with irrelevant properties stripped. The applicationId field is contained in the superclass Application. It is a String ID separate to the database ID used for application management):

```
@Entity
public class SubmittedApplication extends Application {
  /**
   * The list of assigned committee members
   */
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  protected List<AssignedCommitteeMember> assignedCommitteeMembers;
  .. other attributes
}
```

The AssignedCommitteeMember class is here:

```
@Entity
public class AssignedCommitteeMember {
  /**
   * The database ID of this object
   */
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  /**
   * The ID of the application the member is assigned to
   */
  private String applicationId;
  /**
   * The committee member that is assigned
   */
 @OneToOne
 private User user;
 /**
  * Determine if the committee member has finished their review
  */
 private boolean finishReview;
```

I hope I gave enough detail. If more information is needed I am happy to give it. Any help is appreciated